Why can't build iOS app in React Native expo?

I build a project with
npx create-expo-app --template 

And choose Blank (Bare)
A new iOS project with npm run ios  is created but is built on failure. （It worked well several months before)
I tried reinstall Xcode, but it still doesn't work.
But I can build it successfully with Xcode directly (Thank God)
What happened? How to solve this issue? Reinstall macOS ?
